# Advantages of Chain Mail over Studded Leather

Tags: wurm-online

So my goal of becoming a Chain-Smith was slightly hurt when I was looking through the wiki trying to figure out how Quality of the armour affects damage reduction. When I noticed that Studded leather has the same damage reduction as Chain Mail being Moderate ([Source](http://www.wurmpedia.com/index.php/Armour)). Not only that but Chain Mail receives a reduced movement speed and weighs more. Besides being easier to make does Chain Mail even provide better protection then Studded Leather?

Comment: Reading further down the [link](https://www.wurmpedia.com/index.php/Armour) that you provided states the damage reduction multiplier calculation; and also states that chain provides a modifier of 10, whereas studded leather has a modifier of 9. What this means in the final calculation is that chain mail does provide greater damage reduction. At quality level 100, the reduction is an additional 5% (SL: 50%, CM: 55%). At quality level 20, the reduction is an additional 1.8% (SL: 21.2%, CM: 23%) - [Using this tool](http://armynator.de/wurm/armorcalc.php).